# OCS Inventory 2.6 myserveurIP/ocsreports page gives HTTP error 500

Tags: php, perl

I have just made a fresh installation of OCS Inventory 2.6 on a Centos7 VM and everything seems fine. But when I launch the home page at http://**myserverIP**/ocsreports, I got the following message :

"This page isn’t working
**myserverIP** is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

But I've checked almost all config files and I'm unable to figure out where's the issue.

Can someone help me get rid of this trouble ?

Answer (score 0):

There is very vague information given. It would be great if you can provide more info like where is the installation path, what web server are you using etc?

most likely you get 500 when either that page or script doesn't exist where it is expected? so make sure your web server home directory is pointing to right folder.